# Compiling and linking static library with gfortran

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, static-linking

I want to compile some of my often-used Fortran code into a static library (assuming I would have access to both `*.mod` and `*.a` files).
This worked.
However, I have encountered the problem with linking.

Here is an example. Let's say I have `mylib.f90` file:

```
MODULE MYLIB

  IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

  INTEGER FUNCTION FOO(N)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
    FOO = N + 2
  END FUNCTION FOO

END MODULE MYLIB
```

Which is compiled as

```
gfortran -c mylib.f90
ar rcs libmylib.a mylib.o
```

Now, I have a program that uses `FOO` function:

```
PROGRAM MYPROG
  USE MYLIB
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER M

  M = FOO(3)
  WRITE (*,*) M

END PROGRAM MYPROG
```

For simplicity I put it in the same directory as `mylib.mod` and `libmylib.a`. Compilation:

```
gfortran -c myprog.f90
```

no issues. Linking, however results in error:

```
gfortran -L./ -lmylib myprog.o
myprog.o: In function `MAIN__': myprog.f90:(.text+0x11): undefined
reference to `__mylib_MOD_foo' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
status
```

However, symbol `__mylib_MOD_foo` is in `libmylib.a`:

```
nm libmylib.a 

mylib.o:
0000000000000000 T __mylib_MOD_foo
```

and it compiles without a problem if I give it `mylib.o`. What am I doing wrong?

PS. I've seen somewhere, but can't find where now the way to link as follows:

```
gfortran -Wl,--whole-archive libmylib.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive myprog.o
```

It works. But it should solve the problem with weak symbols, whereas the output of `nm` didn't mark `__mylib_MOD_foo` as weak.

Comment: Interestingly, I can also compile it `gfortran myprog.o libmylib.a` and it works...

Comment: What if you put `myprog.o` _before_ the `-lmylib`?

Comment: @francescalus It worked, thanks! But why did the order matter?

Comment: Hopefully those linked questions answer that.